# Multiple CKEditor instances in one form?

Tags: php

I have a form where i need to use the code for attach more rows.

I have a name field(textbox)and a description field(ckeditor)

and an add more link below that . Clicking on the add more will append a row with the above fields .

is it possible to add ckeditor using the attach more option?

Comment: Simply running the CKeditor() constructor on the newly appended element should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it should definitely be possible

once you've created a new description field with a name and ID in your javascript, call CKEDITOR.replace:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('[the new fields name]');
```

(taken from the [CKEditor docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration))